# Add external JS tracking script to tracking/popup.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I want to insert an external js to popup tracking page to get shipping information provided by an API service.

I need to pass the shipping number (that is yet in the popup tracking) to this js... here is the code:

```
<!-- Place this code after <body> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var apiKey = "7b1b7235"; // public APY Key
    var trackingNumber = "HEREPASSTHESHIPPINGNUMBER"; // shipment's tracking number
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.qapla.it/js/1.1/qapla-tracking.js"></script></p>
<p><!-- Place this element where you want to display the Qapla' Tracking -->
<div id="qapla-tracking"></div></p>
```

I use 2 approach:

> 1. edit details.phtml adding the JS but not working
> 2. Insert code in a block and call via widget but I don't know how to call shipping tracking number.

Here where I want to display the tracking 
[image: magento popup tracking]

Here the tracking script
[image: tracking script result]